# Jquery Menu Toggle Switch Hide Element fa fa-bars

Tags: css, jquery, switch, fontawesome, toggle

Прошу помощи, не могу скрыть иконку закрывающего меню под гамбургером, чтобы она появлялась при нажатии на тогл свитч. Код на js отрабатывает правильно, а скрыть никак не получается.

```js
//Menu button

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menu_open").on("click", function() {
    $("navul").removeClass("menu_close").addClass("showing");
  });

  $(".menu_close").on("click", function() {
    $("nav ul").removeClass("showing");
  });
});

$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop()) {
    $('nav').addClass('black');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('black');
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: Quicksand;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(images/10-14-Night.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  transition: 1s;
}

nav.black ul {
  background: #000;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.menu-icon .menu_open {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  text-align: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 16px 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}

.menu-icon .menu_close {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  text-align: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 16px 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}

@media(max-width: 900px) {
  nav ul {
    max-height: 0px;
    background: #000;
  }
  nav.black ul {
    background: #000;
  }
  .showing {
    max-height: 20em;
  }
  nav ul li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 24px 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .menu-icon .menu_open {
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .menu-icon .menu_close {
    display: block;
    z-index: 999;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <title>Навигация</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <nav>
        <div class="menu-icon">
          <i class="menu_open fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
          <i class="menu_close fa fa-times fa-2x"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Вторая Страница</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Третья Страница</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По сути можно тоглить детей, к примеру так:

```js
//Menu button

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menu-icon").on("click", function() {
    $(".menu-icon i").each(function() {
      $( this ).toggle();
    })
  });
});

$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop()) {
    $('nav').addClass('black');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('black');
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: Quicksand;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(images/10-14-Night.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  transition: 1s;
}

nav.black ul {
  background: #000;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.menu-icon .menu_open {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  text-align: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 16px 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}

.menu-icon .menu_close {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  text-align: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 16px 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}

@media(max-width: 900px) {
  nav ul {
    max-height: 0px;
    background: #000;
  }
  nav.black ul {
    background: #000;
  }
  .showing {
    max-height: 20em;
  }
  nav ul li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 24px 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .menu-icon .menu_open {
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .menu-icon .menu_close {
    display: block;
    z-index: 999;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <title>Навигация</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <nav>
        <div class="menu-icon">
          <i class="menu_open fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
          <i class="menu_close fa fa-times fa-2x" style="display: none"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Вторая Страница</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Третья Страница</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Очень помогло! Спасибо вам!